# reshape data and modify the new column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset like the following:

```
data <- data.frame(ID    = rep(1:5,each=4), 
               Event = rep(c("SCR","FUP","FUP","FUP"),5), 
               Date  = c("2016-11-01", "2016-11-10", "2016-12-01", "2017-01-19", 
                         "2017-04-12", "2017-04-04", "2017-05-30", "2017-05-25", 
                         "2018-04-09", "2018-05-02", "2018-05-29", "2018-06-04", 
                         "2017-06-06", "2017-07-26", "2017-09-07", "2017-09-15", 
                         "2016-11-01", "2016-11-10", "2016-12-01", "2017-01-19"))
```

I would like to somehow get it to look like this:

```
ID    SCR         FUP_1        FUP_2        FUP_3
1     2016-11-01  2016-11-10   2016-12-01   2017-01-19
2     2017-04-12  2017-04-04   2017-05-30   2017-05-25
       .
       .
       .
```

I have tried using spread, but it give "Error: Duplicate identifiers". I have also tried reshape:

```
reshape(data, idvar = "ID", timevar = "Event", direction = "wide", sep = "_")
```

but  it removes 2 of the date entries and only takes the first follow up date (see output below)

```
ID   Date_SCR    Date_FUP
1    2016-11-01  2016-11-10
2    2017-03-06  2017-04-12
3    2017-05-25  2017-01-19
4    2018-05-29  2018-06-04
5    2017-07-26  2017-09-07
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to spread the keys FUP_1, FUP_2, and so on, those need to be created. Right now your Events are either FUP or SCR. Can you provide an example with the FUP events labeled with their respective number? That would make it easier to use `spread` in this example.

Comment: ahh, damn I was hoping there was a way to add them automatically, but looks like I will have to add them manually. Once I do this reshape works best as it keeps the original ordering of the events rather than putting them in alphabetical order like spread. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the numbers, I'll use `make.unique`. It isn't pretty, but you can always rename them later (or fix it before-hand).

First, the changed data:

```
data$Event <- ave(as.character(data$Event), data$ID, FUN=make.unique)
head(data)
#     ID Event       Date
# 1.1  1   SCR 2016-11-01
# 1.2  1   FUP 2016-11-10
# 1.3  1 FUP.1 2016-12-01
# 1.4  1 FUP.2 2017-01-19
# 2.5  2   SCR 2017-04-12
# 2.6  2   FUP 2017-04-04
```

Base R, ugly column names, admittedly:

```
reshape(data, idvar = "ID", v.names="Date", timevar="Event", direction="wide")
#      ID   Date.SCR   Date.FUP Date.FUP.1 Date.FUP.2
# 1.1   1 2016-11-01 2016-11-10 2016-12-01 2017-01-19
# 2.5   2 2017-04-12 2017-04-04 2017-05-30 2017-05-25
# 3.9   3 2018-04-09 2018-05-02 2018-05-29 2018-06-04
# 4.13  4 2017-06-06 2017-07-26 2017-09-07 2017-09-15
# 5.17  5 2016-11-01 2016-11-10 2016-12-01 2017-01-19
```

Tidyverse

```
tidyr::spread(data, Event, Date)
#   ID        FUP      FUP.1      FUP.2        SCR
# 1  1 2016-11-10 2016-12-01 2017-01-19 2016-11-01
# 2  2 2017-04-04 2017-05-30 2017-05-25 2017-04-12
# 3  3 2018-05-02 2018-05-29 2018-06-04 2018-04-09
# 4  4 2017-07-26 2017-09-07 2017-09-15 2017-06-06
# 5  5 2016-11-10 2016-12-01 2017-01-19 2016-11-01
```

`data.table`

```
data.table::dcast(data, ID ~ Event)
# Using 'Date' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
#   ID        FUP      FUP.1      FUP.2        SCR
# 1  1 2016-11-10 2016-12-01 2017-01-19 2016-11-01
# 2  2 2017-04-04 2017-05-30 2017-05-25 2017-04-12
# 3  3 2018-05-02 2018-05-29 2018-06-04 2018-04-09
# 4  4 2017-07-26 2017-09-07 2017-09-15 2017-06-06
# 5  5 2016-11-10 2016-12-01 2017-01-19 2016-11-01
```

Comment: `make.unique` is sensible, but the `rbind(by` could be simplified - `data$Event2 <- ave(as.character(data$Event), data$ID, FUN=make.unique)` should do it. If you use `time` as the output variable you can do: `data$time <- ave(as.character(data$Event), data$ID, FUN=make.unique);
reshape(data[c("ID","time","Date")], idvar="ID", direction="wide")`

Comment: I've never been proficient at `ave`, great time to pick up some tricks, thanks @thelatemail! Does it always preserve order?

Comment: I believe it should - it's essentially a wrapper around `split<-`.

Comment: Interesting ... I expect `split` to reorder things ... ahhhh, but I never looked at `split<-`, dang! I've been looking for something like that for a while.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much @r2evans! that make.unique function looks super useful, I'll definitely be using it in the future :)

Comment: There are certainly more elegant ways to automatically number sequentials ... I think the tidyverse has some such functions in there, but I didn't look deeply enough (and don't use them). Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is the 'best' solution, but this would automatically create those _num tags on the ends of the Event values.

```
split(my_data, my_data$ID) %>% 
lapply(function(.id){ group_by(.id, Event) %>% 
mutate(new_event = paste0(Event, "_", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() }) %>%
purrr::reduce(rbind) %>%
dplyr::select(-Event) %>%
as.data.frame()
```

Comment: You might consider using `group_by(my_data, ID, Event)` in place of the `split`/`lapply`/`group_by` combination. Also, I suggest an alternative to `purrr::reduce(rbind)` is `dplyr::bind_rows` ... about twice as fast. Now if you just added `tidyr::spread` to your tidy pipe, you'd have everything requested. Nice.